# MVC - Convert an IDictionary or RouteValueDictionary to object htmlAttributes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I've created a HTML Helper Extension which calls a Editor Template Partial View (MyView) in MVC.

I'm passing additional HTML attributes to the HTML Helper Extension via the object htmlAttributes parameter. In the HTML Helper Extension the The htmlAttributes are converted to an RouteValueCollection (could use IDictionary here) and stored in the ModelProperty object:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor(this HtmlHelper html, ModelProperty prop, object htmlAttributes)
{
    prop.ControlHtmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    return PartialExtensions.Partial(html, "MyView", prop);
}
```

In the 'MyView' Partial View I want to render the control and with the passed HTML attributes so I call:

```
Html.TextArea(Model.ControlName, Model.Value, Model.ControlHtmlAttributes);
```

Howvever this dosnt work because the 3rd parameter should be 'object htmlAttributes' how to I convert the Model.ControlHtmlAttributes to object htmlAttibutes?

Comment: Do you have a typo in your call `Html.TextBox`.  You're extending `TextBoxFor` instead.

Comment: No I'm not using TextBoxFor I 'm using TextFor which takes the following parameters. public static MvcHtmlString TextBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, object value, object htmlAttributes)

Comment: In your partial view you have a TextArea, your html helper is called TextBoxFor, and in the comments you say you're using TextFor? Please pay more attention when you type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer your question anyway:

```
    public static object ToAnonymousObject(this IDictionary<string, object> @this)
    {
        var expandoObject = new ExpandoObject();
        var expandoDictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>) expandoObject;

        foreach (var keyValuePair in @this)
        {
            expandoDictionary.Add(keyValuePair);
        }
        return expandoObject;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Apologies all - this works correctly I used a wrong overload on the `Html.TextArea` so it should read where the second parameter is not an object (as it was in original) but should be a string:

```
Html.TextArea(Model.ControlName, Model.AsString(), Model.ControlHtmlAttributes);
```